# A template from multi projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a template from multi projets but during compile time, I've got error messages:
[image]

The .vstemplate looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Project" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005"
            xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-sdkextension/2010">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>SapLogonPadStarterKit</Name>
    <Description>SapLogonPadStarterKit</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon>sap_starter.png</Icon>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <TemplateID>a7aede48-56d0-4eb3-9058-dab864b8d60e</TemplateID>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>SapLogonPadStarterKit</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>

      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Libraries">
        Libraries\Libraries.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>

      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Libraries_Test">
        Libraries_Test\Libraries_Test.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>

      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="SapLogonPad">
        SapLogonPad\SapLogonPad.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>

      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="SapLogonPadTest">
        SapLogonPadTest\SapLogonPadTest.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>

    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

The project structure looks like:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your namespace RLY $safeprojectname$ ? if not name it something normal and change the error message picture since your 'fake' name is trashing the log

Comment: no no, I have a solution that contains several of projects. I create a template with from projects, that why visual studio give the name $safeprojectname$